# Disable scrolling entirely

Tags: javascript, html, css

Is there a way to make "scrolling" inside an element completely impossible? By that, I mean the content of the element must always keep the same position relative to the element. The element in question has fixed dimensions and `overflow: hidden;`.

I am not talking about preventing the user to scroll inside a certain element, for example by overriding the behaviours of key presses with JavaScript. I don't think doing so would be a good idea as it's impossible to comprehensively predict all the controls of the user and their associated key-bindings. I want to entirely disable scrolling, even when not done by the user.

For example, if the element contains another element with an `id` attribute, accessing this `id` (by clicking a link with `href="#the-id-in-question"`) would automatically cause the content to scroll so that the targeted element (the one with an `id`) is positioned at the top left of its parent.
Another example: if the element in which we want to disable scrolling contains interactive content, tabbing through it will again change the positioning of its content.

Comment: Are you just looking for the absolute position attribute?...

Comment: Do you mean setting the content position to absolute? In which case no, it's not what I'm looking for.

Comment: A `position: fixed` element stays where it is positioned relative to the viewport. Still, you talk about if an element have an `id` one can make the page scroll...well, don't give it an `id` etc. To get a proper answer you have to provide a more visual sample.